# Purchase Mid 2015 MacBook Pro 15" DG

Tags: macbook-pro

Since the new MacBook Pros have been released and the "old" ones happen to be cheaper now, I decided to upgrade to the 2015 model.
On everymac.com, however, I saw that there are two different models of the MacBook: the "IG" (integrated graphics) and the "DG" (dual graphics). Since I'd appreciate higher VRAM, I'd rather go with the "DG" model. However, when configuring the MacBook Pro on Apple's official website, it doesn't seem to offer the "DG" option.

Is there any way to buy the "DG" MacBook Pro directly **from Apple**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoahL is correct when referring to **brand new** 2015 MBPs. However, you can buy what you want directly from Apple if you decide to purchase an [Apple Certified Refurbished](http://www.apple.com/us/shop/goto/special_deals) model.

The exact model you want may or may not be available when you check for refurbished products, but they do come up regularly.

Products refurbished by Apple do come with a full Apple Warranty (and with the option of additional Apple Care). For more info, you can read the [Frequently Asked Questions about Apple Certified Refurbished Products](http://www.apple.com/shop/browse/home/specialdeals/refurbfaq_popup).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually found exactly the one I want! One question though: say a person returned their MacBook and its case got some scratches, is it replaced with a new one or do I need to expect scratches and what not on the MacBook?

Comment: Most units will come without any scratches or marks, but there's no way to be 100% certain. Apple does clean all units before repackaging, but it's _possible_ there could be some light scratches or marks. However, I've only ever seen units that look _brand new_ and I know that in some cases items sold as part of the refurbished program are in fact brand new overstocked units that have been superseded by new models. Also, since you were originally prepared to purchase one at brand new prices, I'd be paying for the extended Apple Care option (especially on dual graphics models).

Comment: @Monomeeth currently there are no available 15" MBPs available. Do they still sell refurb with DG?

Comment: @NoahL Yes, when they're available. From Linus's comment it seems there was one available about 12hrs ago, so hopefully he grabbed it and that's why there isn't one listed now. :)

Answer (score 3):

No. Apple only sells the 2015 MBP with integrated graphics. (Source: Apple retail store employees)